# How to convert string of decimal digits into datetime format in python?

Tags: python

I have a string '06142018123721' which can break down as

```
06 -'Month',
14 - 'Day',
2018 - 'Year'
12 - 'Hour'
34 - 'Minutes'
21 - 'seconds'
```

and I need to convert it into date & time as 06/14/2018 12:37:21. How can I do that?

Comment: Have tried anything yet ?

Comment: You should change your title, since the input is not an integer but rather a string of 14 decimal digits. Do you want the routine to check that the various items and the resulting date and time are valid, or do you want to allow invalid dates and times? In other words, do you actually want a date/time routine or do you want a simple string-handling routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = '06142018123721' 

print( datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m%d%Y%H%M%S").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
06/14/2018 12:37:21
```